# Caching the_content calls

Tags: plugin-development, the-content, cache

I am writing a very small cache plugin called Tiny Cache.
It would cache only `the_content()` calls which take - I think - the longest time to generate during a page load.

I am able to hook the_content and store it in the object cache.

How can this plugin serve cached content? How to stop the_content filter from being processed?

`remove_all_filters()` would destroy all further `the_content()` calls. Maybe a way to stash filters away and restore them later?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first implementation is in a new function called `the_content_cached`.

```
function the_content_cached( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false ) {

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    // Not possible to tie content to post ID
    if ( ! $post_id ) {
        the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
        return;
    }

    $cached = wp_cache_get( $post_id, 'the_content' );
    // Cache miss
    if ( ! $cached ) {
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'tiny_cache_save_the_content', PHP_INT_MAX );
        the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'tiny_cache_save_the_content', PHP_INT_MAX );
        return;
    }

    // Cache hit
    $timestamp = gmdate( 'c' );
    $message_tpl = '<!-- Cached content generated by Tiny cache on %s -->';
    print $cached;
    printf( $message_tpl, $timestamp );
}

// Save the content to the object cache
function tiny_cache_save_the_content( $content ) {

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    // Tie content to post ID
    if ( $post_id ) {
        wp_cache_set( $post_id, $content, 'the_content' );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Is this function solving your issue? according to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284177/any-reason-why-wp-cache-set-not-to-work) answer, `wp_cache_set()` is a non-persistent cache. It can help if you need to request the same content multiple times during page load but won't persist the cached version. It will still process the same query on each load.

Comment: I may not mentioned that persistent object cache is in my default WordPress installation. https://github.com/szepeviktor/wordpress-website-lifecycle