# Any reason why wp_cache_set not to work?

Tags: performance, cache

Any reason why wp_cache_set not to work? I have spun my wheels trying to figure out why these are not working. Any suggestions? These functions are supposed to help me cache the results to a key/object and then leverage the key/object to display the info. However, they are not storing key/object

```
$related_post_ids = wp_cache_get( 'related_post_ids' );
if ( false === $related_post_ids ) {
//seting args and run query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
wp_cache_set('related_post_ids', $the_query, '', 300 );
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate _"Not working"_. What is the problem here? What are you trying to do that you can't get it to work?

Comment: @JackJohansson These functions are supposed to help me cache the results to a key/object and then leverage the key/object to display the info. However, they are not storing key/object , hence not caching

Comment: How do you try to retrieve these values? You might be using a hook that is fired before saving the cache.

Comment: @techtransferportal `wp_cache_*()` is non-persistent. It will be cleared whenever you refresh the page or browser to a new page. For more information read [WP Object Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache).

Comment: Hi @JackJohansson No hooks used, just the above

Comment: Hi @Howdy_McGee , Does that mean cache will remain  if I load page 1 with code above and then use another page to use its cached key/object ? Do you have any sample code to the solution?

Answer (score 22):

As of [WordPress 6.3](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/14/improved-caching-for-database-queries-in-wp_user_query/), both [WP_Query](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3173) and [WP_User_Query](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L820) automatically cache requests. The original question example is outdated since get_posts() uses WP_Query.

---

The `wp_cache_*()` functions are non-persistent caches which will not carry over to the next page request. These functions take advantage of the [WP_Object_Cache](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_object_cache/) class ($wp_object_cache global). Non-persistent caches are be beneficial if you request the same information multiple times during the current page request. For example, if you're retrieving information from an API, you may want to cache the results.

If you're looking to preserve the cache through multiple page loads but optionally expire them after a particular time, you could use [transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/transients/). Transient cache uses the [WP_Object_Cache](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_object_cache/) class but saves the data to the options table for a set time.

Comment: Note that the expire is expressed in seconds, not in milliseconds :-) Great answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are thinking that this function should set a `json object` in browser `local storage` or `cache storage`. But this is not the case. This function still cache but in a non-persistent way. Following example may help you understand it better.

**I have 5 posts displaying on my homepage.**

When page is refreshed 5 posts are loaded which loads template part `'template-parts/content/content.php'`.

Now I have created my own function to load the template for the first time and cache it for rest of 4 times.

```
$cache_key = 'home-template-parts';
$template = wp_cache_get($cache_key, 'template_cache_group');
if (!$template) {
    $template = locate_template(
        array(
            template_path() . "{$slug}-{$name}.php",
            template_path() . "{$slug}.php",
        ),
        false,
        false
    );
    wp_cache_set($cache_key, $template, 'template_cache_group');
}
load_template($template, false);
```

Similarly WordPress `loop`, `database queries` or anything that is loading multiple times can be cached.

**wp_transient API**

On other hand if you do not use wp_transient api carefully your database `wp_options` table will grow slowly over the time. And if table size is large your wp_transient api will be slow.